# Redirect after login is failing more than before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, authentication, authlogic

I'm curious if Browsers are upgrading past what used to work back in the day. I'm getting a lot of feedback from users saying that, after logging in, they are redirected to the homepage, instead of where **they were last at before being prompted with a login**.

My Application Controller :

```
def require_user
  unless current_user
    store_location
    flash[:notice] = "You must be logged in to access this page"
    redirect_to login_url
    return false
  end
end

def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
end

def redirect_back_or_default(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session[:return_to] = nil
end
```

Would you do anything differently here?

I'm using AuthLogic, Rails 2.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for security reasons sometimes the session is reset when a user is logged on. This will clear your redirect information, and this redirect to `default`, which I assume would be the homepage.

The reason to reset session is to avoid [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation).

So either you will have something like

```
before_filter :reset_session, :only => [:create]
```

in your code, Which would reset the session when a user is logged in. Or authlogic now does this by itself.

Solution: use `skip_before_filter`? I have not found a better solution yet myself.

Hope this helps.